# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' (haven't found solution)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, compiler-errors

There's a compile error in my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "command.h"

extern std::istream *instream;
extern std::vector<command> commands;
```

Here is command.h header file:

```
#define CMD_RETURN_TYPE_NONE 0
#define CMD_RETURN_TYPE_STRING 1
#define CMD_RETURN_TYPE_CHAR 2
#define CMD_RETURN_TYPE_INT 3
class command {
    public:
        virtual int getReturnType(void);
        virtual char getOpName(void);
        virtual void* call(void);
}
```

throws next compile error

```
1>------ Build started: Project: MyFirstCPPApp, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>MyFirstCPPApp.cpp
1>e:\anton\msvc++ projects\myfirstcppapp\myfirstcppapp\MyFirstCPPApp.h(5) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>e:\anton\msvc++ projects\myfirstcppapp\myfirstcppapp\MyFirstCPPApp.h(5) : error C2377: 'std::istream' : redefinition; typedef cannot be overloaded with any other symbol
1>        E:\Anton\MSVS2008Express\VC\include\iosfwd(707) : see declaration of 'std::istream'
1>e:\anton\msvc++ projects\myfirstcppapp\myfirstcppapp\MyFirstCPPApp.h(5) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>.\MyFirstCPPApp.cpp(4) : error C2039: 'get' : is not a member of 'System::Int32'
1>        c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll : see declaration of 'System::Int32'
1>.\MyFirstCPPApp.cpp(7) : error C3861: 'callCmd': identifier not found
1>.\MyFirstCPPApp.cpp(11) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'std::istream *' to 'int *'
1>        Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>Build log was saved at "file://e:\Anton\MSVC++ Projects\MyFirstCPPApp\MyFirstCPPApp\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>MyFirstCPPApp - 6 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I haven't found solution, how to fix it?

Comment: What is `command`?  `command.h` respectively.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ yeah, command.h, it's abstract class

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34653404/edit) your question to add such information.

Comment: You cannot store abstract classes in a vector. Rather use a pointer.

Comment: You are missing a `;` after the class definition.

Comment: Yes, for abstract classes you need a vector of pointers or even better smart pointers.

Comment: I haven't put `;` because i'm started coding C++ after Java, but there is no need for `;` after classes in Java

Comment: @username.ak That's like saying "I don't say 'the' or 'a' in English, because there are no articles in Russian." C++ is not Java, treat it as a distinct language. The language can *talk* about similar concepts, but it uses its own grammar, words, and terminology to do so.

Comment: Really, i'm porting Java code to C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing ; after:

class command {
...
}**;**

Whatever is in between the closing bracket and the semicolon (signifying end of the line) will be parsed as an optional list of objects that belong to this class.

Thus, it is necessary to add the semicolon after class definition so the compiler knows that whatever comes after this class definition isn't part of the list of objects.